# Django Paginator. Нестандартное использование

Tags: python, django

Модель

```
class Book(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    chapter = models.IntegerField()
```

Представление

```
class Book(TemplateView):
    template_name = "book.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            page_num = self.request.GET['page']
        except KeyError:
            page_num = 1

        context['book'] = Book.objects.all()

        paginator = Paginator(context['book'], 6)

        context['data'] = paginator.get_page(page_num)

        return context
```

Поле chapter - это глава книги.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на ссылки происходил переход на страницу определенной главы книги со всеми ее записями(поле text).

Возможно ли это сделать средствами пагинатора Django?
Вроде есть `class Page(object_list, number, paginator)`

Comment: Почему бы не сделать класс `Book` и класс `Chapter`, у которого было бы поле `book` - внешний ключ на класс `Book`?

Comment: А зачем это нужно? Главы разные.

Comment: В любом случае это не имеет отношения к моей задаче

Comment: Главы разные, а книга одна?

Comment: да, как в обычной книге